How can I FREE <leader><space> from Telescope?
I use the  combination as the prefix to many of my key-mappings. Without that prefix many of my custom definitions go away. LazyVim has assigned already it to Telescope find_files and I can't undo it without touching the source code.
Basically the question how to change the builtin key-mappings? (Not only ADDING the new ones)
Thanks

Found the right response which works for me:
vim.keymap.del('n', '<leader><space>', {})

